# Find out most frequent strings in section of file

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a file that looks like this:

```
o99 ksad<tab>abcde
$%!H$!(<tab>00
!sdaf as<tab>12
sarwa 
&!§! &%
```

(where *`<tab>`* represents a real TAB character).

For clarification: It contains two "columns", the second might be entirely empty, the first might contain spaces and various symbols. For example the last two rows in the sample-input above contain nothing in the second column. The columns are seperated by a tab.

I’m looking for a way to find the most frequent strings in the first column. The output could be either (preferably) a file that is sorted by this frequency or a separate output-file listing the most frequent number-strings in order.

I’m using Linux.

Comment: 1. Where are the tabs in this example file? I think you can write `<tab>` in the example data, since the formatting doesn't allow "real" tabs. 2. What do you mean by "most frequent"? Do you mean in total? In the example data, I don't see a string appearing out multiple times. What would be the desired output of that example data? Maybe you need to expand your example data too.

Comment: What _Linux_ is that? ChromeOS, Android, OpenWRT, Ubuntu or other GNU based system? The kernel has little incidence here on this Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cut -f1 file | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

- `cut` uses TAB as the default field delimiter; `-f1` selects the first field.
- `uniq -c`  to count the number of (contiguous) repetitions,
- `sort -rn` to sort numerical order, reversed.

---

\thanks{Jeff Schaller}

Comment: just to make it explicit, cut will use TAB as the default delimiter.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, thank you, I will add it and some complmentary explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Mandatory awk solution

```
awk -F"\t" '{column[$1]++}END{for (var in column) print column[var]"\t"var}' INPUTFILE.txt | sort -nr -k1
```